# Verifying A Proof That $\pi=\log\left(-\sum\limits_{s=0}^{\infty}(1-s)\frac{\zeta(s)}{\xi(s)}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, volume, riemann-zeta, pi

I write $\zeta(s)$ for the Riemann zeta function. I denote Riemann's xi-function by $\xi(s).$ Here $s$ is a a whole number greater than or equal to zero.

> **Problem**: Show that 
>   $$
> \pi=\log\left(-\sum\limits_{s=0}^{\infty}(1-s)\frac{\zeta(s)}{\xi(s)}\right).
> $$

---

**My Attempt At A Solution**: This is just an exercise in substitutions. Following *Ahlfors* Chapter 5.4.3 he derives Riemann's xi(s)-function, denoted $\xi(s)$ as:
$$
\xi(s)=(1-s)\left[\frac{(s/2)\Gamma(s/2)}{\pi^{s/2}}\right]\zeta(s)
$$
On the other hand I have the following equation for the volume of the unit-ball in $s-$dimensional Euclidean space
$$
\frac{\pi^{s/2}}{(s/2)\Gamma(s/2)}.
$$ 
The bracketed term of Riemann's xi function is simply the inverse of the volume of the $s-$ball, which for short handedness I will denote by $\nu(s).$  After substitution I write
$$
\xi(s)=(1-s)\frac{\zeta(s)}{\nu(s)}.
$$
Subsequently,
$$
\frac{\xi(s)}{(1-s)\zeta(s)}=\frac{1}{\nu(s)}.
$$
Of course at $s=1$, we have a pole at $\zeta(s).$ However in this case $1-s=0$  and so we have a cancellation.

Now, whenever $s\equiv 0\pmod2,$ 
$
\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\nu(s)=e^{\pi}.
$
***And so, whenever $s$ is an even number***:
$$
e^{\pi}=-\sum\limits_{s=0}^{\infty}(1-s)\frac{\zeta(s)}{\xi(s)}
$$
Note the content of the summation is negative and the negative of a negative is positive and so we can take our logarithm,
$$
\pi=\log\left(-\sum\limits_{s=0}^{\infty}(1-s)\frac{\zeta(s)}{\xi(s)}\right).
$$
I checked my solution using Wolfram Alpha: [check.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28-sum+%5Bzeta%5B2*n%5D*%281-2*n%29%5D%2FRiemannXi%5B2*n%5D+from+n%3D0+to+infinity%29)

Comment: Proceeding to the last expression, you interchanged the role of $\zeta$ and $\xi$.

Comment: Gary -thank you. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Note that there is no need to cite Gelfond since $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\nu (2n)}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\pi ^n }}{{n\Gamma (n)}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\pi ^n }}{{\Gamma (n + 1)}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\pi ^n }}{{n!}}}  = e^\pi .$$

Comment: @Gary - would it help the "proof" if I remove the sentence on Gelfond and replace it with your resut ?

Comment: Well, you can also state the main problem as $$
\pi  = \log \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {(2n - 1)\frac{{\zeta (2n)}}{{\xi (2n)}}} } \right).$$ Of couse, it is not so interesting since what is under the logarithm is just $e^\pi$ written in an unnecessarily conplicated form.

Comment: @Gary - I wrote as much as $s$ is an even number and so is equal to some number of the form $2k.$ I also mention it is an exercise in substitution. I am simply asking if I at least got that right.

Comment: At the very beginning you just say $s$ is a whole number, which means it could well be odd. Anyway, your derivation is correct.